# How do you create a regression with multiple variables and fixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a large data set and want to regress variable X on variables A, B, C, D, and E and also include fixed effect variables Y, Z. I want to use the natural log of the variable C as well (plus one).

How can I go about this?

My intuition was to use felm

```
install.packages("lfe")
library(lfe)
regress <- felm(formula= X ~ A, B, C, D, E + W + Y + Z)
regress
```

Comment: I think the formula would be: `formula= X ~ A+B+C+D | E + W + Y + Z`

Comment: And generally you can put logged variables in formulas just as `log(c)`. It's not clear why this should be "intuitive" unless you have a fairly wide experience with mixed effects modeling in R. You have not described your data in sufficient detail to know if `felm` is appropriate. The lfe package is not being actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using felm rather than the standard lm?

Have you already read through the [felm documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfe/versions/2.8-7.1/topics/felm)? You may be able to figure out how to use the function from their examples.

In addition, R formula objects don't ever contain commas. If they do, the parser will assume part of the formula is another argument to the function and an error will result.